# How to get zfs to use a higher portion of the cache device? (Currently using 5GB / 480GB)

Tags: zfs, zfsonlinux

I am running a 4 disk raid 10 setup with a fast 480GB SSD.

When looking at iostat -v the cache device has only 5GB of allocated space and the rest is free.

Both `primarycache` and `secondarycache` are set to `all`.

How can zfs be set to fill up the cache as much as possible (use most if not all of the 480GB)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will use the cache as it's populated and necessary.

If you're not doing much reading activity, you won't see much L2ARC cache usage.